# How to use my datastore preference in fragment kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, datastore, preference

```
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("app_preferences")
```

I want to use the datastore above but the variable cannot be read or used in the fragment. like this picture
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `dataStore` reference in `Fragment`

```kotlin
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("app_preferences")


// in Fragment
val pref = requireContext().dataStore
```

Comment: I placed the Context.dataStore in the application viewModel and then access it in each fragment with recommendation val pref - requireContext().dataStore.

Answer (score 0):

To read from a preferences dataStore, you must use the corresponding key type function to define a key for each value that you need to store in the DataStore instance. For example, to define a key for an int value, use intPreferencesKey(). Then, use the DataStore.data property to expose the appropriate stored value using a Flow:

```
val EXAMPLE_COUNTER = intPreferencesKey("example_counter")
val exampleCounterFlow: Flow<Int> = context.dataStore.data
  .map { preferences ->
    // No type safety.
    preferences[EXAMPLE_COUNTER] ?: 0
}
```

for more information refer to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore

Answer (score 0):

First in your fragment before onViewCreated:

```
 private lateinit var dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>
```

Then inside onViewCreated:

```
 dataStore = context?.createDataStore(name = "MyDataStoreSettings")!!
```

Cheers!